# Find a point that divides a line segment in a specific way

Tags: geometry

Given $A(-12, 5)$ and $B(12, 29)$,   find the point that divides the line segment $[AB]$ three-eighths of the way from $A$ to $B$.

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: What attempts have you made to find a solution? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The distance formula.

Comment: Hint: to find the answer, you can solve this "divide in the required proportion" question separately for the $x$-coordinate and for the $y$-coordinate.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I tried the distance formula but was not sure if it was what i needed. I am terrible with fractions so i am not sure how to get it to 3/8 of the distance from a to b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a vector method, you can save a lot of work, compared to L. Salvetti's answer.

The line segment starts at $A$ and ends at $B$, so we transform this by shifting $A$ to the origin, and $B$ to the point $B-A$.

We want three-eighths of this vector, so we multiply by $\frac{3}{8}$.

Finally, we add $A$ to return the line segment and therefore the dividing point to their correct positions.

The desired point is $$p=\frac{3}{8}(B-A)+A=\frac{3}{8}B+\frac{5}{8}A=\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 14\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $dAB$ be the distance between points $A(-12,5)$ and $B(12,29)$. We have:

$$dAB=\sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2+(y_b-y_a)^2}=\sqrt{(12-(-12))^2+(29-5)^2}=\sqrt{24^2+24^2}=24\sqrt2$$

Then, $\frac{3}{8}dAB=\frac{3}{8}.24\sqrt2=9\sqrt2$

Now, we need to find a point $P(x,y)$ such that: $(1)$ lies on the segment $AB$ and $(2)$ $dAP=\frac{3}{8}dAB=9\sqrt2$, where it follows:

$$dAP=\sqrt{(x-(-12))^2+(y-5)^2}=\sqrt{(x+12)^2+(y-5)^2}=9\sqrt2$$

Squaring both sides:

$$\tag{2} (x+12)^2+(y-5)^2=162$$

We are done with condition $(2)$, but now we need to find the equation of the segment $AB$: $y-y_a=m(x-x_b)$ with $-12<x<12$ and $5<y<29$

$$m=\frac{y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}=\frac{29-5}{12-(-12)}=\frac{24}{24}=1$$

Therefore, the equation wanted is: $\tag{1} y-5=x+12 \Rightarrow y=x+17$

Substituting $(1)$ in $(2)$:

$$(x+12)^2+(x+17-5)^2=162$$
$$(x+12)^2+(x+12)^2=162$$
$$2(x+12)^2=162$$
$$(x+12)^2=81$$
$$|x+12|=9$$

Where we get: $x_1=-3 \Rightarrow y_1=14$ or $x_2=-21 \Rightarrow y_2=-4$, but the point $(x_2,y_2)$ is not on the segment $AB$. Hence, $P(-3,14)$ is the point wanted